# Soundpool not working

Tags: android

I'm doing a simple game and since I need some short sound effects, I thought the Soundpool would be appropriate. But it's not working! I don't get any sounds! I have checked my code over and over again and also compared it with several other examples, but still not working! I'm confused and need some help to get it to work.

Here is my code. Have I missed something or could I do it in another way? preciated some help! Thanks!

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(4,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

soundPoolMap.put(0, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.bonk2, 1));
soundPool.play(0, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);

soundPool.release();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you have mentioned any Sound ID as 0, instead you should mention the Sound ID of the loaded sound using `load()` method.

For example:

```
 soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
 soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                  int status) {
           loaded = true;
       }
 });
 soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
 soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

Check this example: [Tutorial: Play sounds via SoundPool](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html#tutorial_soundpool)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get a red error line below .load, and I wonder why? Can I not place this code in any of my classes or does it has to be in a certain class to get .load to work?! I hope you understand my question

Comment: @3D-kreativ I hope you have checked example link I have given

Comment: Yes, but I only had some problem at the beginning, but now I have created an inner class in the MainActivity that loads the sounds. Then I can call methods in this inner class to play sounds from other classes. Works perfect.

Comment: @3D-kreativ superb, enjoy !!